# WCF Rest Service POSTS on local IIS but not on server (GET works in both)

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I have a WCF service that I have added RESTful support to. GET/POST works on my local IIS. However on the server POSTS gives me the following error:

> The incoming HTTP request's URI 'http://myserver:9002/StudyService.svc/rest/RestAuthenticateUser' does not match any service operation.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/RestAuthenticateUser", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    authResultDTO RestAuthenticateUser(AuthRequest authRequest);

public authResultDTO RestAuthenticateUser(AuthRequest authRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

I am posting through Postman: http://myserver:9002/StudyService.svc/rest/RestAuthenticateUser

```
content-type: application/json
body: raw      JSON
{
    "DomainName": "Local",
    "UserID": "myuser",
    "Password": "mypassword"
}
```

I am looking into .net installs on the server. I am thinking that maybe it is more of a environment issue instead of a coding?

Target framework: .Net Framework 4.5

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the GET method allows multiple parameters, POST allows only one parameter passed as the body of the request.

You either pass some of the parameters in the URI string

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/RestAuthenticateUser/{userID}/{password}/{applicationId}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    authResultDTO RestAuthenticateUser(AuthRequest authRequest);

public authResultDTO AuthenticateUser(string domainName, string userID, string password, string applicationId)
{
    ...
}
```

Or you use a data contract

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://yournamespace.com")]
public class MyContract
{
   [DataMember(Order=1)]
   public string DomainName { get(); set{};}

   [DataMember(Order=2)]
   public string UserID { get(); set{};}

   ...
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/RestAuthenticateUser", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    authResultDTO RestAuthenticateUser(AuthRequest authRequest);

public authResultDTO AuthenticateUser(MyContract contract)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will give the second option a try. I have updated my question to make it more clear what does and doesn't work on the server vs the development machine.

Comment: I am not sure how this is working on your local IIS as you cannot pass multiple parameters in a Post request along with the fact the parameter names are different between the body (upper case) and the function (lower case)

Comment: The second option with the DataContract and DataMember was the fix.